# APE-Project and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, reverse-ajax

I am attempting to utilize the reverse-ajax project [APE-Project](http://www.ape-project.org/home.html) with ASP.NET MVC and wondering if anyone has had any experience utilizing this project with ASP.NET and can provide some advice accordingly ?

Is there something better to use than this [APE is free however so its +++]

Thx

Answer (score 2):

It's non-free, but if you're looking for a reverse ajax/comet server that's simple to use and integrates completely with ASP.NET/IIS, you're looking for [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync).